# Picture display distorded on iPad

Tags: jquery, ios, css, html, ipad

I am trying to display a photo in my page and just on  the iPad that the photo is displaying  distorted. It displays  just fine on the iPhone and else where but the iPad, any idea what I can do to solve this? I have a test page to show the issues I am having, thanks!

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>
<br>
 Test <br><br>
<table border="1">
   <tr>
  <td>

 <div id="box">
  <div id="top"></div>

     <div id="boxcontent">

       <div class="container">
         <a href="#">
           <img src="#" alt="" title="" width="" height=""/>
         </a>
       </div>

       <span style="color:#a1a1a1;font-weight:normal;font-size: 10px;">by </span>
       <a href="#" onclick="window.location.reload( true );">
         <span style="color:#2FB3DE;font-weight:normal;font-size: 12px;">User</span>
       </a>

       <span style="color:#ff5113;font-weight:normal;font-size: 10px;">on 03-29-2014 08:51 AM</span>
            <!-- here is the picture getting distorted on display -->
         <div>
           <img src="my_pic.jpg"  width="288" height="384" id="image_x" style="padding: 18px 10px 10px 7px ; float:center;clear:both;"/>
         </div>

         <p style="color:#ffffff;font-weight:normal;font-size: 12px;"> Just waiting.  </p>

     </div>

     <div id="bottom" >
       <p style="text-align:center; vertical-align: middle;color:#a1a1a1;font-weight:normal;font-size: 10px;">Comments 111</p>
     </div>

   </div>
   <div style="height:5px;"></div>
</div>

</td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: 1. In what way is it getting distorted? 2. In a jsFiddle with a placeholder image, it works just fine on my iPad: http://jsfiddle.net/YH3MR/1/

Comment: I am using  iPad-mini and the image shows squished.

Comment: The issue is that the original position of the picture is in landscape and I need to display it in portrait. Do I need a special CSS for the iPad to make the rotation?

Comment: I guess I don't understand you. What is the original size of the image? Are you trying to rotate the image?

Comment: This is the original size - width="288" height="384" - I need to find out a way to display this image in portrait no matter what.